# How to break string data coming from Api response in Laravel

Tags: laravel-8

This my data coming from Api : "TAX_BREAKUP": "ab=4835,ay=1400,at=852,cb=4835,cy=1400,ct=852"
@foreach(explode(',', $data['TAX_BREAKUP']) as $amt)

Adult Price₹ {{$amt}}

Tax{{$amt}}

@endforeach
An this is code which I am trying to break the string.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, Please rewrite your question clearly so that we could understand the problem and give help.

Comment: I am getting "ab=4835,ay=1400,at=852,cb=4835,cy=1400,ct=852" as a sting in api response but I want to break that string and use particular values how I can do that in laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, what you want is :

```
$Tax_arr = explode(',', $data['TAX_BREAKUP']);

foreach($Tax_arr as $amt){
    
    $amt_arr = explode('=', $amt);
    
    echo $amt_arr[0]." is ".$amt_arr[1]."<br>";
}
```

`$amt_arr[0]` is the attribute name and `$amt_arr[1]` is the value

Comment: @ShivamBhardwaj, please click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.